# In sqlite3, convert binary string to a decimal number

Tags: sqlite

Is there a way to convert the binary to a decimal number in sqlite3?

For example: I would like the query returns 200 for '11001000'

Thanks

Comment: *200 for '10101010'*? Why?

Comment: Sorry, I pasted the wrong string. Thank you for pointing it.

Comment: I guess you could make a table with 256 rows in which you could look up all the possible values...